# VBA: Store value to variable

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

```
Sub test() ' ' test Macro '

    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set aRange = Range("A1:A255")
    
    Range("A1").Select
    For i = 1 To aRange.Count - 1
    
        If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "Last name") Then
            Call CopyContents
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
        
    Next i
    
End Sub


Sub CopyContents()
    Dim currentRange As Range
    Dim genderAndDiscipline As String

    Set currentRange = Range(ActiveCell.Address)
    
    'get the gender and dicipline
    Set genderAndDiscipline = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    'genderAndDiscipline = genderAndDiscipline.Split(" ")
    
End Sub
```

I'm trying to store a cell value in a variable. But somehow it's keep giving me an compile error:

> Object required

In my opinion, I'm telling the variable to aspect a string and the cell is containing a string, as the debugger says.

The currentRange is 'A7' here and the cell above is containing a string with '200m men'

The error occurs at
`Set genderAndDiscipline = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value`

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: Try removing the `Set` keyword from that line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`genderAndDiscipline` is declared as a string.

The correct way to assign to a string is using `Let` instead of `Set` (which is used for assigning objects).

In order to get rid of the error, remove the word `Set` from the line causing the error, or replace `Set` with `Let`.

That is, use one of the following two alternatives (which are equivalent):

```
genderAndDiscipline = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
```

or

```
Let genderAndDiscipline = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Set` keyword works with `Objects`. Since you are looking just to save the value, you should leave this out. i.e. Change:

```
Set genderAndDiscipline = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
```

to:

```
genderAndDiscipline = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Set` from `Set genderAndDiscipline = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value`